# Get percentage from sum of column values

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs5

In the following example I have a grid with a widgetcolumn with the percentage of the sum of the total value of another column:

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1uh5

However, I could not print the widgetcolumn.

I needed to get exactly the same precentage values in the precent column.

Any ideas how to do this without a dataindex config and client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain why you don't want to use dataIndex config?

I've found workaround, but it's an ugly solution. I do not recommend to use it in production environment. Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1uhg

In short, you need to calculate sum of all values and keep it outside of the renderer. On each render you count percentage and format it as you want.

```
renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
        var me = this;

        if (me.sum === 0) {
            store.getRange().forEach(function(rec) {
                me.sum += rec.get('value');
            } );
        }

        return Ext.util.Format.round(100*record.get('value')/me.sum, 0);
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to store the sum on `me` there.

Comment: Why do you think so? 
`me` is the component object. I count sum once and keep it. It's better than iterate through the store every time.

Comment: I think you should keep the sum on the store and attach a datachanged listener to recalculate the sum when the store content changes.

Comment: That's the best way. As I get the question correct, we can only change renderer function.

Comment: @Nikolai Thanks. If possible I want to do these percentage calculations on the client side, Any solution using renderer function or another one that resolves can be used in my case. I am studying your solution that seems to be a possible solution and it seems to work well.

Comment: What I meant by not using dataindex was saying that the values for this percentage column would not be sent server-side. There is no particular inconvenience in using datindex config if this contribute to the solution.
What I want to solve is the need to display the percentages in a column and can not do this with a widgetcolumn because, I could not print that column or export to pdf the grid with that type of column.

Comment: @Alexandre about using a datachanged listener, can you give me an idea how do you do this?

Comment: @josei I've updated the fiddle. I moved sum calculation to the store and force recalculation after datachanged event.

Comment: @Nikolai Lopin Thanks. This helps a lot. Works great.